# How can I make a statement in .map to make a <div>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that contains letters, and I have a .map that displays them

```
 const rptSentence = newSentence.map((a) => (
        <>
          <p
            style={{
              display: "inline-block",
              whiteSpace: "pre",
              zoom: a.ifBold ? 1.4 : 1,
              color: a.ifBold ? "black" : "# 999999",
            }}
            className={
              bolds.includes(a.id)
                ? "letterBold letterregular"
                : ifCatch.includes(a.id)
                ? "letterCatch letterregular"
                : "letterregular"
            }
            key={a.id}
            onClick={() => changeHandler(a)}
          >
            {a.letter}
          </p>
        </>
      ))
```

It presents me well, the problem is that because each letter is a paragraph in itself. So when the word reaches the end of the page it goes down a line in the middle of a word.

Is it possible to somehow set in .map condition (letter === ""? ...) that will open and close  tags or something like that that will make each word line a block in itself?

[image: print screen]

I added an example.
The words are cut in the middle - (the red marking - this is a marking that shows a word cut in the middle)
I marked with a yellow stripe first and last word where I want to somehow insert a div tag or something so that it does not cut

Regards

Comment: Sounds like you're asking how to split a sentence string into words? (also, no need to wrap a single <p> in <>...</>)

Comment: Can you post a sample of your new expected output in HTML format? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: Please tag the framework too

Comment: @adiga I edited the post with an example

Comment: You need to properly split the array *before* calling `.map()` on it. If you need a bunch of <p>s inside <div>s, use two nested `.map()` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 rptSentence2 = maxArr.map(function (headers) {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          display: "inline-block",
          marginLeft: 10,
        }}
        key={headers}
      >
        {newSentence
          .filter((b) => b.numWord === headers)
          .map(function (a) {
            return (
              <p
                style={{
                  display: "inline-block",
                  whiteSpace: "pre",
                  zoom: a.ifBold ? 1.4 : 1,
                  color: a.ifBold ? "black" : "#999999",
                }}
                className={
                  bolds.includes(a.id)
                    ? "letterBold letterregular"
                    : ifCatch.includes(a.id)
                    ? "letterCatch letterregular"
                    : "letterregular"
                }
                key={a.id}
                onClick={() => changeHandler(a)}
              >
                {a.letter}
              </p>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator directly inside map i.e. :

```js
 const rptSentence = newSentence.map ((a) => (
    a.letter===""?null:
    <>
      <p
        style = {{
          display: "inline-block",
          whiteSpace: "pre",
          zoom: a.ifBold? 1.4: 1,
          color: a.ifBold? "black": "# 999999",
        }}
        className = {
          bolds.includes (a.id)
            ? "letterBold letterregular"
            : ifCatch.includes (a.id)
            ? "letterCatch letterregular"
            : "letterregular"
        }
        key = {a.id}
        onClick = {() => changeHandler (a)}
      >
        {a.letter}
      </p>
    </>
```

Comment: I think that's the direction.

The problem is that if I do
a.letter === ""? </div> <div>:
Writes an error message because I have to do in case of a word ending first a parenthesis of a div and only then a new div opening. Because in "" mode it means a word is over and then I want to "close" the previous word and "open" a new word.